# Was Calvin's statements on church membership consistent across all his versions of the Institutes?

Tags: ecclesiology, calvin, membership

We know that Calvin wrote on church membership:

4.2.8

> But as here full certainty was not necessary, he has in its place substituted the judgment of charity, by which we acknowledge all as members of the Church who by confession of faith,
> regularity of conduct, and participation in the sacraments, unite with us in acknowledging the same God and Christ.

4.2.9

> Such persons we do not approve by our suffrage as members of the Church, but we leave them the place which they hold among the people of God, until they are legitimately deprived of it.

I saw a friend write:

> Calvin was inconsistent on his position on church membership. They were included and then excluded from various versions of his Institutes.

My question is: **Was Calvin's statements on church membership consistent across all his versions of the Institutes?**

Comment: Calvin, following Romans 2:28-29, spoke of a *visible* church, and of a *spiritual* one.